# Sharepoint Reports do not work in Firefox

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs

Using SSRS in integrated mode, Reports can be viewed in IE but not in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc.  They get "An unexpected error occurred while connecting to the report server. Verify that the report server is available and configured for SharePoint integrated mode." (Oh, and it also happens to one IE user on the domain as well)

It might be a double hop issue, since we do have a dual farm (frontend and report server).  I've been following directions pertaining to double hop authentication, and I'm currently using setspn, all to no avail.  I cannot find anyone else with this problem.  This is really frustrating.

Comment: Thanks but that does not seem to work.  Our network is named local.mycompany.com and I tried that, and mycompany.com and even the IP address of the Report Server.  The error comes back very fast and I cannot find any log messages anywhere.

Comment: Chris, wait, I did a variation on your comment and it works!  I set "network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris" AND "network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris". I set them both to our web application name which is "http://intranet". You should make this into your answer so I can accept it.  This is great, I've been trying to get this working for over a month, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox by default has NTLM and Kerberos authentication disabled. Websites smart enough to detect this give an appropriate error page. SharePoint isn't that smart.

Enable Negotiated authentication by opening "about:config", search for "network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris" and set it to the domain name your SP server is in (ie if your SP server is `sp.example.com`, set the value to `example.com`). You may need to se the "network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris" too, depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint requires ActiveX for variety of it's features to function properly. While I don't have experience with integrated mode, I know that using browsers aside from IE will limit your Sharepoint capabilities.

It would also help if you described your network setup (Sharepoint version, etc) to help with troubleshooting.

Comment: I've got SSRS reports in our company SP2010 site open right now. They look identical to viewing them in IE. While SP might have some ActiveX in it still, it's not terribly common to run across.

Comment: We are using WSS 3.0 version 12.0.0.6548, with the Frontend web server on Essential Business Server 2008, and the other Sharepoint server is Windows Server 2003 with Reporting Services and SQL Server 2008 standard.  I doubt it is an ActiveX issue since this also happens on an one IE browser as well, which I reset to defaults, but I will double check.  We are not using any special webparts or anything.

Comment: In addition, the Reporting Services Authentication Mode in Central Administration is set to Windows Authentication.  In rsreportserver.config the Authentication section is as follows:  <AuthenticationTypes>
   <RSWindowsNTLM/>
   <RSWindowsNegotiate/>
  </AuthenticationTypes>